# Python: Find newest files based on names

Tags: python

I have a directory with lots of files under a user home dir (/home/sebas/):

```
abc_11.txt
abc_22.txt
xyz_01_11.txt
xyz_01_22.txt
hello_01.py
hello_02.py
```

I am trying to get the newest file based on names. So the output from above directory should be abc_22.txt and xyz_01_22.txt and hello_02.py. This is what I wrote.

```
def sorted_get_latest_file(path, *paths):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, *paths)
    list_of_files = glob.glob(fullpath)                    
    for i in list_of_files:
        print os.path.split(i)[-1]
        j = sorted(os.path.split(i)[-1],  key=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
        print j
```

This is what I am getting:

```
abc_11.txt
['_', '.', '1', '1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 't', 't', 'x']
abc_22.txt
['_', '.', '2', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 't', 't', 'x']
pr.txt
['.', 'p', 'r', 't', 't', 'x']
xyz_11.txt
['_', '.', '1', '1', 't', 't', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'z']
xyz_22.txt
['_', '.', '2', '2', 't', 't', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: is `xyz_02_11` newer than `xyz_01_22`? or is 'newer' only accounting for the last 2 digits?

Comment: What's the logic to find the newest file? Right now, you're sorting characters in a string, not strings in a list.

Comment: You are sorting each file by itself, which means sorting the string... perhaps you meant: `sorted([os.path.split(i)[-1] for i in list_of_files],  key=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])`

Comment: @AChampion : I already something like this, it print all files sorted and I only want it to print:  ` 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_22.txt', 'pr.txt'] ` and not all files. ` ['abc_11.txt', 'xyz_11.txt', 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_22.txt', 'pr.txt']
['abc_11.txt', 'xyz_11.txt', 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_22.txt', 'pr.txt']
['abc_11.txt', 'xyz_11.txt', 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_22.txt', 'pr.txt']
['abc_11.txt', 'xyz_11.txt', 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_22.txt', 'pr.txt']
['abc_11.txt', 'xyz_11.txt', 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_22.txt', 'pr.txt'] `

Comment: @MooingRawr: In that case  `xyz_02_11` will be newest.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting a single filename, not a list of filenames:

```
>>> list_of_files = glob.glob(fullpath)
>>> sorted([os.path.split(i)[-1] for i in list_of_files], key=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
['hello_01.py', 'hello_02.py', 'abc_11.txt', 
 'xyz_01_11.txt', 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_01_22.txt']
```

Comment: a = <list of files>. In that case I could do something like this:  `j = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
    print j `

Comment: Yes... and if you need it reverse just add `reverse=True`. Then you can slice off the top...

Comment: its close, let me search more. output from above: ` ['pr.txt', 'abc_22.txt', 'xyz_22.txt', 'abc_11.txt', 'xyz_11.txt'] ` I want it to print only `abc_22.txt, xyz_22.txt and pr.txt`